# Unity and Google VR - Cardboard: Start game with the head rotation set to zero or glazing to the same point always

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, rotation, google-cardboard, google-vr

In the game view of Unity, when the game start, it is glazing to the same point always. The head has rotation of (0,0,0) when the game start always.

Unfortunately that does not happen when I compile and push to my Android phone. When the game start, maybe the player needs to turn his body 180 degrees because the path he have to follow is behind (hopefully he will turn his body: if the player turns 180 his head, probably he will die).

By the way, that happens when the second scene loads. The first scene seems to be OK. The problems happens when I do `UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene ("GameScene");`

I have tried to add the following piece of code both right before calling `LoadScene` and at the end of a `Start` function of GameScene:

```
cardboardHead.GetComponent<Transform> ().rotation = Quaternion.identity;
```

However it seems we cannot change that value on runtime as when I modify it at runtime in Unity, it instantly change back the value it had.

A workaround would work is changing the parent rotation in the way that follows: if the rotation of the head is 156, the the parent game object of the head would be -156. That should work but it is not an elegant solution.

Comment: Also tried in the Awake function to add `head.GetComponent<Transform> ().rotation = Quaternion.identity;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the Cardboard SDK you have a function to do that recenter

```
Cardboard.SDK.Recenter ();
```

Try it instead of directly modifying the camera transform. Because you need the headtracker to change it's orientation.

**UPDATE**: the above code works for the older versions of Google Cardboard. Nowadays it has been renamed to Google VR and the above code has been change to the following:

```
GvrViewer.Instance.Recenter ();
```

Comment: It works! Well I had to adapt your Google Cardboard code to the nowadays Google VR code. I was stubborn looking in the head code, but the "magic" function was in its parent. I have added the line of code to a Start function of one of my scripts and it is working beautifully. Thank you! :)

Comment: if you would be kind to upvote,  fighting for my first upvote ! glad to be of help

Comment: If it the up vote helps to keep you helping people, I'm more that happy to up vote! Thank you! :)

Comment: Careful as this is known to sometimes introduce drift: [https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/357](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/357)